# Issue about hibernate and JFreechart

Tags: java, hibernate, jfreechart

I have a problem. After putting `gnujaxp.jar` from JFreechart Libs. my application won't work anymore. I'ts throwing a problem

```
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:101)
```

I'm sure that the `gnujaxp.jar` from the JFreechart library is the one causing the problem. because after i removed it again. my application work again.

My Question is. How do i solve this problem. or if there really is a conflict between hibernate and jfreechart, is there some alternative in generating graphs? thanks

Comment: [Old version](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=26653)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for alternatives, try out [XChart](http://xeiam.com/xchart.jsp). Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the project. We've been working on version 2.0.0 coming out soon, which will include a lot of neat stuff including bar and area charts, a style manager, right-click-save-as, logarithmic axes, and themes. It's designed to be super light weight and there are NO dependencies. If you have any feature requests, feel free to add them [here](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart/issues?state=open).